# How to add random array value to each character?

Tags: php

I want to add random array values to each character

```
<?php
//array_rand ( array $array [, int $num = 1 ] ) 
$input = array("1","2","3");
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2);
$random = $input[$rand_keys[0]];
$str = "ABCDEFG";
$newstr = substr_replace($str, $random, 1, 0);
echo $newstr
?>
```

**Expectation :**

ABCDEFG = A1B3C1D2E3F2G

Comment: why did you remove last number for character `G` ?  it should be `A*B*C*D*E*F*G*` where `*` will be any number from `[1,2,3]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `foreach`, Added random number after each character from given set of number or array element.

```
<?php
$str = "ABCDEFG";
$randomNumber = [1,2,3];
$strArr = str_split($str);
$strWithRandomNumber = "";
foreach($strArr as $str){
    $strWithRandomNumber .= ($str.$randomNumber[array_rand($randomNumber,1)]);
}
echo $strWithRandomNumber;
?>
```

Live Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e5a60fe5f42bb0e4afcaa2df4ffefe2b0974685a

Output example:

```
A2B3C1D2E2F2G2
```

Comment: Happy Coding. Be safe and healthy.